# Xamarin forms: ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage, but no webview in my project

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, app-store

Yesterday I have pushed a new app to AppStore, but it gets rejected with the following error.

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

In my knowledge, this issue usually occurs due to the use of `Webview`. I have one `Webview` in my project, so I decided to remove it (Since that part is currently not using in the project). I have pushed the app again to AppStore after removing the `Webview`, but again my app gets rejected with the same error. After that I do a clean, rebuild, and deleted the bin, obj folders. 2 times my app gets rejected from Appstore after removing `Webview`.

**See the below screenshot: No `Webviews` are available for the entire solution.**

[image]

Are there any other reasons for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems an existing issue of Xamarin.forms on iOS .

1. Make sure that the version Xamarin.Forms is 4.6 or higher and Xamarin.iOS is 13.10.0.17 or higher.
2. Change the Linker Behavior to SDK Only or Link All and then add the
   additional arguments: `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type`
   Please check all of these have been set under the release
   configuration and iPhone platform.

For more details you could refer
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/